# I am trying to add and image with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem with PHP and Wordpress.

I am trying to add an image with PHP but it does not work

I try to add it between `href="">mycode image</a>`

```
$image_url='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1256/1256650.svg';


$link = sprintf( "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='%s' onclick='%s' aria-label='%s'> $image_url</a>",
            esc_url( add_query_arg( 'replytocom', $comment->comment_ID, get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) . "#" . $args['respond_id'],
            $onclick,
            esc_attr( sprintf( $args['reply_to_text'], $comment->comment_author ) ),
            $args['reply_text']
);
```

Comment: The sprintf formatting is correct and works if you passed in static strings. You should echo/dump out all your input parameters to see that you are getting the expected data. ie... var_dump( $image_url, esc_url( add_query_arg( 'replytocom', $comment->comment_ID, get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ), $args['respond_id'], $onclick, esc_attr(
sprintf( $args['reply_to_text'], $comment->comment_author ) , $args['reply_text']); die();

Comment: '*I tried several times and used many codes but to no avail*' - Show us your attempts. This is very basic HTML / PHP. P.S. At the very least spell WordPress correctly.

Comment: pls tell me  how  i use  the right code ???

Comment: but image  not show ??

Comment: @ahmmed did you try testing the values coming by using the var_dump I supplied. Can you share the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind the url of the image to the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.
This is basic HTML behavior:

```
$image_url='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1256/1256650.svg';


$link = sprintf( "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='%s' onclick='%s' aria-label='%s'> <img src=\"$image_url\" /></a>",
            esc_url( add_query_arg( 'replytocom', $comment->comment_ID, get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) . "#" . $args['respond_id'],
            $onclick,
            esc_attr( sprintf( $args['reply_to_text'], $comment->comment_author ) ),
            $args['reply_text']
);
```